# C++ ath.c:193: _gcry_ath_mutex_lock: Assertion `*lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)' failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I am working at a multithreaded application and when I start multiple threads I get this erro:

```
ath.c:193: _gcry_ath_mutex_lock: Assertion `*lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)' failed.
```

I use libcurl, liboauth to get http requests.
I read about that is a bug in libcurl or something like this
Has anyone a solution or a similar problem?

Comment: Forgot to initialize a mutex somewhere? That's what googling the error message seems to indicate.

Comment: No. I also get this error when I have no mutexes in there

Comment: Obviously you are using libgcrypt in there, either directly or through some library (liboauth?). Multithreaded use of gcrypt requires initialization, as documented at http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Multi_002dThreading.html - either you forgot it, or one of the maintainers of libraries you used did. Check the documentation...

Comment: The problem was that more than one thread tries to get a http request at the same time. That's not possible. So I used mutexes to avoid that.